# NVIDIA X Server settings empty

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xserver, gpu-driver

It is me again!
After my previous problem I went to service - https://askubuntu.com/questions/847193/problem-with-boot
.The boot problem is gone - it had something to do with nvidia driver update. At sevice they said it was popular problem if u had 2 videocards.

Now I have other,probably not that hard to solve problem. I can do everything but my PC uses only intel inetgrated videocard.[Additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQHS5.png) Others will give me error that led to previous problem with boot, so I instantly change it back to default - Nouveau driver. I think it has something to do with [NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G64uV.png)

Any help, how to fix it, so I could use other drivers?

p.s. I already tried to install nvidia-370 which is shown as recommended, but it X server is empty anyway.